# pandas: str.contains method to select only elements from a list

Tags: python, pandas

**I would like to keep the rows of a `pd.DataFrame` for which a column contains ONLY values from a list, that is, all of the comma-separated values are in the whitelist.**

Is there a way to achieve this (ideally in a one-liner) using `Series.str` methods?

For instance, using `contains()` on this example

```
whitelist = ["a", "b"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["b", "a,c", "b,c,d", "a,b"]})
df[df.x.str.contains("|".join(whitelist))]
```

gives

```
    x
0   b
1   a,c
2   b,c,d
3   a,b
```

but I would like the result to be

```
    x
0   b
3   a,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` operations with [`issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
S = set(whitelist)

out = df[[S.issuperset(x.split(',')) for x in df['x']]]

# equivalent to
# out = df[[all(w in S for w in x.split(',')) for x in df['x']]]
```

Another variant suggested by @Chrysophylaxs
:

```
out = df[df['x'].str.split(',').apply(set) <= set(whitelist)]
```

Output:

```
     x
0    b
3  a,b
```

Comment: Just for fun, using only string operations: `out = df[df['x'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(whitelist)})")[0].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).eq(df['x'])]`

Comment: Hijacked your solution to come up with: `mask = df["x"].str.split(',').apply(set) <= set(whitelist)` :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs yes, that's another possibility :)